# Why doesn't float() throw an exception when the argument is outside the range of a Python float?

Tags: python, floating-point

I'm using `Python 3.10` and I have:

```py
a = int(2 ** 1023 * (1 + (1 - 2 ** -52)))
```

Now, the value of `a` is the biggest integer value in [double precision floating point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

So, I'm expecting `float(a + 1)` to give an `OverflowError` error, as noted in [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float):

> If the argument is outside the range of a Python float, an OverflowError will be raised.

But, to my surprise, it doesn't throw the error, instead, it happily returns:

```
1.7976931348623157e+308
```

which seems like `sys.float_info.max`.

I also do `float(a + 2)`, `float(a + 3)`, `float(a + 4)`, etc but it still returns `1.7976931348623157e+308`. Only until I do `float(a + a)` then it throws the expected exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: int too large to convert to float
```

It seems like the smallest number that fails is `a + 2 ** 970`, as noted in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75320937/why-doesnt-float-throw-an-exception-when-the-argument-is-outside-the-range-of#comment132907424_75320937).

So, what could be the reason for this?

Comment: For me it throws well before a+a.

Comment: @KellyBundy I only check to `float(a + 10)`. My point is not about how big `k` is in `float(a + k)`, but why it doesn't throw for every `k >= 1`.

Comment: Right, but it seems to start failing around a+(a>>53), which might give some insight.

Comment: Might be caused by the variable floating points density: very high around 0, and very low towards the "interval edges", where between 2 "consecutive" values (that only differ by the *LSB* - mantissa) there's a huge gap.

Comment: Smallest natural number that fails for me: `a + 2**970`

Comment: Assuming CPython and a system whose C `double` uses the IEEE 754 binary64 floating-point format, conversion in Python from `int` to `float` is correctly rounded under the round-ties-to-even mode, following the rules of IEEE 754. Values *slightly* larger than `DBL_MAX` will therefore round down to `DBL_MAX`. The cutoff lies at `2**1024 - 2**970`, exactly halfway between `DBL_MAX` and `2**1024`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was commented, 2**970 is the smallest addition that rounds up.  This makes sense as follows:

```
 1023 =exp
-  52 =n, where the "smallest" field is 2**-n
-----
  971
                                        L G RS
so, the largest is: (2**1023)*1.111...111(1)00
                                123...012 3 45  // bit #s
                                ^     555 5 55
                          2**1022       ^ ^
                                        ^ ^
                                  2**-971 ^
                                          ^
                                          ^
                                          2**970
```

...so adding 2**970 will round up, per the LGRS=1100 values.  These are the Least significant, Guard, Round, and Sticky bits from the IEEE 754 spec.

This can be demo'd in python as follows:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print("%100.10f" % (sys.float_info.max))
179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.0000000000
>>> # note that even though this is even in base 10, the significand is odd in binary since the Least significant bit is 1
... 
>>> print("%f" % (sys.float_info.max+2**970))
inf
>>> print("%100.10f" % (sys.float_info.max+2**969))
179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.0000000000
>>>
```

Comment: Do you have a link to some page explaining "Guard" etc? I didn't find it on Wikipedia.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm supposed to get from the demo at the end, but `print(sys.float_info.max.hex())` might be clearer? [Demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PzO3IL@oRKG4spiroCgzr0QDyNJLy8lPLInPzEvL18tNrNDLSK3Q0NSEymNRoG2kpWVpbqBJnEIzS5jC//8B)

Comment: Re “These are the Least significant, Guard, Round, and Sticky bits from the IEEE 754 spec”: These are not in the IEEE 754 standard.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil  And ???  I do not have a copy since it cost money, but the Lsb and GRS bits are SOP -- see http://euler.ecs.umass.edu/arith/parts-pdf/Part4b-flp.pdf; https://ee.usc.edu/~redekopp/cs356/slides/CS356Unit3_FP.pdf; https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~david/courses/cs552/S12/handouts/guardbits.pdf; ad nauseam/etc.

Comment: Third-party descriptions of implementations of some floating-point arithmetic operations, particularly addition and subtraction, often use guard, round, and sticky bits, but they are not required by the IEEE 754 standard. Implementors of the standard are not required to implement or use guard, round, or sticky bits.

Comment: @Kelly Bundy sys.float_info.max = 2 ** 1023 * (1 + (1 - 2 ** -52)) = 2 ** 1023 * (2 - 2 ** -52) = 2 ** 1023 * (2 - 2**-52) = 2**1023+1) - 2**(1023-52) = 2**1024 - 2**971 = 179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368 = 0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023 (from sys.float_info.max.hex())

Comment: @Eric Postpischil hmmm... I did not knw that.  So, it's more of a "how it works" thing -vs- these bits actually to existing in ckt(s) and/or S/W, I guess?

Answer (score -4):

Because this is the last value that can be inserted into float, and it includes this value itself, which means that any number that is greater than this value will already return an error.